# My GoogleTv Fishtank device not functioning

Tags: android, google-tv

I was part of the googletv fishtank program. I'm having an issue getting the correct software updates. I cannot see the googletv apps marketplace, movies, etc..

I have firmware version 3.1
Build number: fishtank_appdev-eng 3.1 MASTER 8066 test-keys 2011/10/14-22:18

I know the program has ended but would like to develop on this device. The googletv group has been closed for a while.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Fishtank development devices cannot be updated with the Android Market since they're root-able devices.  Fill out the form at http://goo.gl/tVw4i and the Google TV team will contact you if there are consumer devices available for developers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the basis for the policy of not allowing the Market on root-able devices? The allowing of the distribution of GApps in the Cyanogenmod project shows that Google is not too concerned.